# Why is there Identical Files in Report And Feeds API for Amazon PHP Library?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I had Downloaded fresh copy of PHP Library for FeedsAPI and ReportsAPI

I was trying to include client.php of both api because i want to call feeds api for some operation and reporting api for getting requesting report.

But when i executed my code it says that

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class MarketplaceWebService_Model in /mnt/hgfs/keyur On My Mac/webs/keyur.iec.com/htdocs/vendors/AmazonAPI/ReportsAPIClass/src/MarketplaceWebService/Model.php
```

so i looked at all files and folders in both of this api and found that there are same number of files and they are identical because i did diff on each files using Netbeans  and there was no difference at all.

If this is case than why there are to two API with same files?

I am using
Reports API Section Client Library - PHP - Version 2009-01-01
About this Library

Based on the 2009-01-01 API version.
Refers only to the amazon-mws-v20090901-php-2011-08-01.zip file.

AND

Feeds API Section Client Library - PHP - Version 2009-01-01
About this Library

Based on the 2009-01-01 API version.
Refers only to the amazon-mws-v20090901-php-2011-08-01.zip file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same with the c# version too. It looks like they are the same code just put into 1 file. Not sure why they could not do this for all the section really. Would of made more sense and kept things tidy.

I have read that the API is basically the source code for the AMTU which Amazon used to use, this could explain why, and when converting to different languages they kept it all the same.

Only Amazon knows why they have done this really.